# Sorting the output of `ps`

Tags: process, sort, ps

I am trying to understand why `ps` does not behave the way I expect it to. From the man pages, the following command should display `ppid` and `lstart`, with items sorted by `lstart` order. However when I run the same command in three different terminals:

First term:

```
gauthier@sobel:~/ $ ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
21142 Tue Dec 16 13:45:18 2014
 3383 Mon Dec 15 15:40:35 2014
```

Second term:

```
gauthier@sobel:~/bin $ ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
19595 Tue Dec 16 13:45:03 2014
 3383 Mon Dec 15 14:49:14 2014
```

Third term:

```
gauthier@sobel:~ $ ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
 3383 Tue Dec 16 13:39:05 2014
16357 Tue Dec 16 13:45:12 2014
```

There are several things I don't understand here.

- items in terms 1 and 2 are sorted most recent first. Items in term 3 are sorted oldest first. Even considering alphabetical order the orders differ.
- PPID 3383 is the same for all three terms, but at different start times. It seems that several distinct PPID might be the same although they are different processes?

---

System info:

```
$ ps -V
procps-ng version 3.3.9
$ uname -a
Linux sobel 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: PPID is the parent PID. A process can spawn any number (within limits) of child processes pretty much any time it wants. You're showing the parent PID but the child start time.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Still, the dates are not sorted the same in all three cases.

Comment: Yes, sort order is strange. Can you specify what OS & version of ps you have? (`ps -V`)

Comment: Edited to add system info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps --sort=lstart` doesn't actually sort by `lstart`, 
According to [this serverfault comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/27887/how-to-sort-ps-output-by-process-start-time#comment385502_27893):

> `lstart` gives a full timestamp, but cannot be used as a sort key.
>   `start_time gives` the usual 'time within the last 24 hours, date
>   otherwise' column, and can be used as a sort key.

This is implicitly documented in `ps`'s man pages, where `lstart` is not listed under the `OBSOLETE SORT KEYS` section, but `start_time` is.

The [source code](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/source/663045859a0af8f942ea9ffda6450fd0ffdfa0b8:ps/output.c) also backs this up, see this definition starting on line 1506:

```
/* Many of these are placeholders for unsupported options. */
static const format_struct format_array[] = {
/* code       header     print()      sort()    width need vendor flags  */
[...]
{"lstart",    "STARTED", pr_lstart,   sr_nop,    24,   0,    XXX, ET|RIGHT},
[...]
{"start_time", "START",  pr_stime,    sr_start_time, 5, 0,   LNx, ET|RIGHT},
[...]
};
```

**Edit**: expanded on the explanation on the right answer, and removed the misleading part of the original one.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what weird internal format is used to store `lstart`, that doesn't make sorting the chronological order. The serverfault comment was the solution (using `start_time` instead of `lstart`). Quote this in your answer and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually the bit about the output formatting was a red herring. I edited my answer to contain only the part about the unusable sort comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I try on my gnu/gentoo, no such problem, here it is:

```
 ~ # ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
 3851 Mon Dec 15 21:25:51 2014
 4037 Mon Dec 15 21:25:52 2014
 4042 Tue Dec 16 22:02:24 2014
 ~ # ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
 3851 Mon Dec 15 21:25:51 2014
 4037 Mon Dec 15 21:25:52 2014
 4042 Tue Dec 16 22:02:25 2014
 ~ # ps -o ppid -o lstart --sort=lstart
 PPID                  STARTED
 3851 Mon Dec 15 21:25:51 2014
 4037 Mon Dec 15 21:25:52 2014
 4042 Tue Dec 16 22:02:26 2014
 ~ # ps -V
procps-ng version 3.3.9
 ~ # uname -a
Linux  3.12.21-gentoo-r1 #9 SMP Fri Nov 28 18:59:44 CST 2014 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Aren't you running these in a single terminal? All the PPIDs and start dates are the same.